# Why does temporary struct member not have the expected value in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc

Consider this code:

```
#include<iostream>

struct A
{
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    int c = (A() = A{2}).b;  // Why is c zero after this?
    std::cout << "c = " << c << std::endl;
    std::cout << "A.b = " << (A() = A{2}).b << std::endl;
}
```

In my mind this is two equivalent ways to print the same value, but I get this result (on GCC 7.3.0 under MinGW):

```
c = 0
A.b = 2
```

I would have expected `c` to be 2. Can anyone explain why it is 0?

Comment: The reason is a GCC bug. Recent GCC versions behave correctly.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica You are right, updating to GCC 11.2.0 solved this and it makes sense (since the observed behavior does not make sense). Please, feel free to post this as the answer (optimally, it would be nice with a bug reference, but after a quick browse at [GCC Bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/), I think that is an effort too large for the benefit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mentioned by @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71369087/why-does-temporary-struct-member-not-have-the-expected-value-in-c#comment126149481_71369087), this is a GCC bug. I tested several versions on godbolt.com. Here's what I found:

- works as expected on gcc 6.* with c++ 11 and 14
- fails on gcc 7.*, 8.*, 9.1-4 with c++14
- works on gcc 7.*, 8.*, 9.* with c++11
- works on gcc 9.5 with c++14
- works on gcc 10 with c++ 11 and 14

I compiled with `-O3`, and tested *some* with `-O0`, and optimization level didn't make a difference where I tested.

I'm not sure where to find the bug ticket. [Here's a link to the change summary for GCC 9 versions](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/changes.html), and [Here's a link to the bugzilla tickets resolved by 9.5](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_status=RESOLVED&resolution=FIXED&target_milestone=9.5). I didn't see anything that looked like an exact match. Either I missed it, or the ticket didn't get put in that list (which the change summary page mentions is a possibility).

> This list might not be complete (that is, it is possible that some PRs that have been fixed are not listed here).